# Arrays and Spinners

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I have a very specific task that needs to be completed using the following elements.
I have to develop a login page, in that page I have to create a drop down box (spinner) which I have done. The Spinner contains 4 names. However when the name is selected from the drop box, the user must enter a pass code (4 digit number). This is where it gets tricky and I need help. I must use arrays to connect the names from the spinner with a set of 4 hard coded pass codes that are relevant to each user e.g. user1 pass code is 1234, else invalid pass code. 
I have asked for help regarding this particular topic and some people have suggested different methods, but I must stress that I need to use parallel arrays for this page.
I will include some code that I have been trying to use. My question is how can i connect my arrays to the spinners so that the user selected must enter their specific pass code?
At present I am unable to connect the user to their specific pass code when entered.

```
     my spinner contains four names// spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.names);
  ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
   R.array.names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 my passcode login //public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
  int count)
   {
  if (passcodeEntered.getText().toString().length() == 4)
  {
     if ((passcodeEntered.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1234")))
     {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Summary.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

     } else
     {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Passcode",          

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     finally here is some code I was trying to use in my arrays//

  public void passCodes(){

  String[] names = {"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"};
  String [] passcodes = {"1234", "4321", "5678", "8765"};
  int passcode = keyboard.nextInt();

  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
  {



     if (passcodes[i]==passcode){
        System.out.println("Go to next page");
        System.out.println(names[i]);
     }

  }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: I dont know how to get it working. I cant get the names to match up with the pass codes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the setOnItemSelectedListener

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
  //here check for the position, this will tell you which item in the dropdown was selected by the user. You can use this position as index to get the passcode from the array and match it with the passcode entered by user here and accordingly either call another activity or throw Toast message to user. 


}
```

});

You can refer to [this blog](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/android-spinner-how-to-set-default-value.html) for an example on spinner handling.